# inserting into table values from jsp page

Tags: mysql, jsp, insert

this is my jsp page

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import = "dbutil.*" %>
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<form>
    <body>
        <table border="2" width="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>NEW USER  </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td> Email: </td>
                    <td><input type="email" name="t1" value=""  required/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="t2" value="" required /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Name: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="t3" value="" required /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mobile:</td>
                     <td><input type= "text" name="t4" value="" pattern ="\d{10}"    required /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit " name="b1" /></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <%
            if (request.getParameter("b1") != null) {
                System.out.println("yo yo yo ");
                String email1 = request.getParameter("t1");
                String pass1 = request.getParameter("t2");
                String name1 = request.getParameter("t3");
                String mob1 = request.getParameter("t4");

                String sql = "insert into userinfo(email,pass,mobile,name) values('" +          email1
                        + "','" + pass1 + "','" + mob1 + "','" + name1 + "')";
                DBconnect x = new DBconnect();
                x.QueryExecuter(sql);

            }
        %>
    </body>
</form>


</html>
```

this does not insert the values in the table names *userinfo* .
Its a login page

when i run the file it shows the page and after we enter the values it takes it but it doesnot  insert it into the table .
The DBconnect is the class i have made for a commen connection.

```
package dbutil;

import java.sql.*;

public class DBconnect {


Connection  conn;


public DBconnect()
{
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn =     DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employeemanagement","root","root")     ;

    }
    catch ( Exception e)
    {
     System.out.println(e);
    }
}
public void QueryExecuter (String sql){
try
{
    Statement stat;
        stat = conn.createStatement();
    stat.execute(sql);
    stat.close();
    conn.close();


 }

 catch(Exception e)
 {
     System.out.println(e);
 }
 }


public ResultSet QueryReturner(String sql)
{
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try
    {
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stat.executeQuery(sql);


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    return rs;
  }
 }
```

Comment: so what's the problem? You don't know how to retrieve the values from the submitted form? Don't know how to write an SQL `INSERT` query? Given that your DB stuff never actually DOES anything except define some helper methods, I'm guessing it's the latter.

Comment: i have written the query but when i check in the table the values are not inserted .

Comment: i am not able to understand where the problem is

Comment: where are you submitting the form? what `Submit` button does here?

Comment: submit button executes the insert query thats all i want the form to do .

Comment: the problem is that you're just defining an object. You don't actually **USE** that object. e.g. instantiate it, call methods, etc... Then you don't have any actual SQL to pass in to those methods. In other words, you've got a recipe book, and can't understand why supper doesn't magically appear on your plate.

Comment: i made an object of dbconnect class and from there i called the sql statement . I m not understanding what u are saying .

Comment: what should i do to make it work properly

Answer (score 0):

Change

> stat.execute(sql);

for

> stat.executeUpdate(sql);

Comment: no it does'nt work . i have tried inserting the values direct command from the command executon window  and then it works fine.

Comment: why would you close the statement or the connection?

Comment: its just like that i have done many projects like that . moreover i dont think its a problem if we close it and then again connect it

Comment: moreover it shows this warning   warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5
1 warning

Comment: sorry, i might have seen your problem now.
You cant put a try catch in a constructor.
You can see this if you debug the app and set a break point in here...

Comment: I dont think there is a problem with try and catch becoz this is the commen class i use for connection ti other projects and it works fine there . so over here i have only changed the database name

Answer (score -1):

```
String sql = "insert into userinfo(email,pass,mobile,name) values('" + email1 + "','" + pass1 + "','" + mob1 + "','" + name1 + "');";
```

I think you need to provide a semi colon after the SQL statement. It worked for me.